# Making a decision without using if

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, osx-mavericks

I have a code like this:

```
MyClass *object = [self nextValidObject];
```

The method `nextValidObject` will return nil if there is no new object to return or the next object available.

After that I have a value I have to fetch from an array, something like

```
NSArray *myArray = @[@"aaa", @"bbb"];
```

I want to fetch "aaa" if object is nil and "bbb" if it is not.

I know, I can do this:

```
NSString *myString = object ? @"aaa" : @"bbb";
```

or

```
NSString *myString = object ? myArray[0] : myArray[1];
```

but I was thinking on something like

```
NSString *myString = myArray[ ... some magic here ... ];
```

by some magic I wonder if there is a way to cast (I don't know if this is the correct word) 0 to nil and 1 to not nil, so I can use object there.

Comment: @iphonic that is still an 'if'

Comment: One big question: WHY?

Comment: the big answer: why not?

Comment: Because this is Objective-C and not some other language you may wish you were using. :)

Comment: Because it's kind of waste of time. And if you can see in the answer of hypercrypt the possible solution is far less readable than the most verbose if statement. But maybe this is what you seek.

Comment: @dasdom - exactly what I want! 

Comment: Are you trying to use the second element in the array if the "object" is nil? What about using an NSDictionary to specify key value pairs where the value is either a 1 or 0. Still unsure what you want to do

Comment: @user2778894 *why not?* Because when you write code that changes its behavior is non-obvious ways, your colleagues are very likely to stop trusting your code and, by extension, you. You should strive to write code that's a clear as possible and avoid doing sneaky things. Unless there's some significant benefit (and you haven't shown us that there is), there's no sense in making things more difficult than they need to be.

Comment: I really hope this isn't for production code.

Comment: There are reasons to avoid branching: http://eprint.iacr.org/2014/140.pdf I doubt this is one of those cases though.

Comment: Your use of the ternary operator is wrong. You would get bbb if your object is nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to branch you could do something like this:

```
NSString *myString = myArray[(NSUInteger)ceil((double)(intptr_t)(__bridge void *)object / ((double)(intptr_t)(__bridge void *)object + 1))];
```

There is probably a better way than this, but I can't think right now. It shows the idea though.

Actually, having thought about this the following will work and be more readable:

```
myArray[(intptr_t)(__bridge void *)object && 1];
```

Branching isn't that bad though, unless there are specific reasons why you want to avoid branching.

Comment: OMG it burns my eyes!

Comment: And mine. There are times where you really want to avoid branching, but I don't think this is one: http://eprint.iacr.org/2014/140.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Although, there are explicit `if`-clauses in

```
NSArray myString = object ? @"aaa" : @"bbb";
```

is called a [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/?%3a), which is in many programming languages a "shortcut" for if clauses. You could use casts:

```
NSObject *object = nil; 
int i = (int)(object || 0); // i = 0 
// if object is not nil i = 1
```

But I would not recommend it to use this in software development. There is a reason why if-clauses are used and helpful. :-) I do not understand why you want to avoid if-clauses.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why you want to do this but you can go

```
int i = 1;
NSString *myString;
do {
    myString = myArray[i--];
} while (object && i >= 0);
```

No ifs..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSString *myString = myArray[ (nextValidObject ? 1 : 0) ];
```

Not all that different from what you are already doing, but at least the decision happens inside the square brackets, as you seem to want. Not magic, but it's what I would probably write...

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C is C and in C the relational and equality operators return an integer value - `1` if the  condition is true, `0` if it is false. So the expression:

```
object != nil
```

has the value `1` if object is not `nil`, and `0` if it is. Nothing more complicated is required.

Answer (score -1):

You have `NSArray *myArray = @[@"aaa", @"bbb"];`

You want myArray[1], which equals "bbb", when object is nil.

pseudocode:

```
if object equal nil
    index := 1
else
    index := 0
myString := myArray[index]
```

Objective C:

```
NSInteger index = (object != nil);
NSString *myString = [myArray objectAtIndex:index];
```

Comment: please add some explanation of your proposed solution and what the questioner was missing or doing wrong.